# ¿Por qué da error cuando creo la instancia?

Tags: java, poo, objeto, constructor, ide

Les pongo en situación, tengo dos clases, una clase llamada `Hora` y otra llamada `Hora12` donde `Hora12` hereda los atributos de la clase `Hora` a través de la palabra reservada `extends`. Hasta ahí todo bien, ahora, en la segunda clase he de definir un `enum` e incorporarlo en el constructor del mismo, pues bien, lo he hecho; a la hora de ejecutar el código creando la siguiente instancia:

```
Hora12 h5 = new Hora12(12, 12, Meridiano.PM)
```

donde los primeros dos elementos son la hora y los minutos, me da el siguiente error en el IDE:

> The constructor Hora12(int, int, Meridiano) is undefined

Revisando las `Quick Fixes` de Eclipse me recomienda que cree otro constructor con exactamente las mismas propiedades que el que ya tengo definido:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego no soy capaz de averiguar el motivo del error, dejo aquí el código intentado:

Clase Hora12:

```
    public class Hora12 extends Hora {
    
    public enum Meridiano { AM, PM }
    protected Meridiano mer;
    
    public Hora12(int hora, int minuto, Meridiano pm) {
        
    super(hora, minuto);
    
    this.hora = hora;
    this.minuto = minuto;
    this.mer = pm;
        
    }
}
```

Clase Principal (TestHora):

```
    package org.ip.sesion07;

public class TestHora {
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        enum Meridiano {PM, AM};
    

        
        Hora12 h5 = new Hora12(12, 12, Meridiano.PM);
        
        
        
        
        
    }
    

}
```

Comment: Tienes el enum `Meridiano` definido en dos archivos diferentes. Cual de los dos es el que acepta tu constructor? Ese es el problema, en la clase Hora12 le dices que tiene en el constructor un parámetro de tipo `Hora12.Meridiano` mientras que luego desde tu main le estás intentando pasar otro enum diferente. Cuando la instancias deberías poner `Hora12.Meridiano.PM` en vez de usar el definido en tu clase `TestHora`... que dos enum se llamen igual no significa que sean el mismo enum.

Comment: @Benito-B Solucionado! Gracias por tu colaboración